# keep duplicates using `make_clean_names` in R janitor package

Tags: r, janitor

I am trying to **clean a character column** using `make_clean_names` function in `janitor` package in R. I need to keep the duplicated in this case and not add a numeric to it. Is this possible? My code is like this

```
x <- c(' x y z', 'xyz', 'x123x', 'xy()','xyz','xyz')

janitor::make_clean_names(x)
[1] "x_y_z" "xyz"   "x123x" "xy"    "xyz_2" "xyz_3"

janitor::make_clean_names(x, unique_sep = '.')
[1] "x_y_z" "xyz"   "x123x" "xy"    "xyz.1" "xyz.2"

janitor::make_clean_names(x, unique_sep = NULL)
[1] "x_y_z" "xyz"   "x123x" "xy"    "xyz_2" "xyz_3"
```

Using `unique_sep = NULL` doesn't seem to work. Any other way to keep unique values?

Desired Output:

```
[1] "x_y_z" "xyz"   "x123x" "xy"    "xyz" "xyz"
```

I know how to use regular expressions to do this. Just searching for a shortcut.

PS: I know this function is created to clean names of a data.frame, I am trying to apply this to a different use case. This functionality might help a lot in cleaning character columns.

Comment: it will be very hard to do any analysis with the same variable name. For example if you did `mean(df$xyz)` what column would R choose? In most operations it will throw and error if these are columns in a dataframe. I would recommend against this.

Comment: As I mentioned I am trying to clean a character column. I am not using to clean column names of a data frame.

Comment: Just trying to repurpose the function to some other use case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**
As of janitor 2.2.0, this is now possible with `allow_dupes = TRUE`:

```
x <- c(' x y z', 'xyz', 'x123x', 'xy()','xyz','xyz')
janitor::make_clean_names(x, allow_dupes = TRUE)

[1] "x_y_z" "xyz"   "x123x" "xy"    "xyz"   "xyz"
```

*I overrode my original, obsolete answer with this new one.*

Comment: Thank you. Another function with this feature will be very useful to clean character and factor columns! Nice work with this package. It helped me a lot!

Comment: FYI since your original post and comment, this is now possible in janitor.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sapply` to go through the vector elements one by one and thus avoid adding numeric suffixes to duplicates:

```
sapply(x, make_clean_names, USE.NAMES = F)
[1] "x_y_z" "xyz"   "x123x" "xy"    "xyz"   "xyz"
```

Comment: This is a clever solution!  Much easier than my suggestion of writing a new function.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works for this and dataframes. Its faster than `dplyr::rowwise()`

```r
 tibble::as_tibble(c(' x y z', 'xyz', 'x123x', 'xy()','xyz','xyz')) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(.data$value)%>% 
  dplyr::mutate(x2 = janitor::make_clean_names(dplyr::cur_group()$value)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```